# supersized captions not working with wordpress

Tags: php, javascript, wordpress, supersized

I am working with a multisite WP platform.

Supersized images are loading, but I am not getting the thumbnail tray, progress loading bar, captions, transitions or nav arrows. It seems like jquery/jquery.supersized does not realize there are multiple images.

I have tried to duplicate the script loading from the [supersized site](http://buildinternet.com/project/supersized/slideshow/3.2/demo.html), but to no avail. In a sense, load exactly what the demo loads to try to bug out the issue.

Here is what is in my header:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" <?php language_attributes() ?>>
<head profile="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
    <title><?php wp_title( '-', true, 'right' ); echo wp_specialchars( get_bloginfo('name'), 1 ) ?></title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="<?php bloginfo('html_type') ?>; charset=<?php bloginfo('charset') ?>" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url') ?>" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() ?>/css/supersized.core.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() ?>/css/supersized.shutter.css" />

    <link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo('pingback_url') ?>" />
    <?php wp_head() // For plugins ?>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() ?>/js/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() ?>/js/supersized.3.2.6.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() ?>/js/supersized.shutter.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    jQuery(function($){

                $.supersized({

                    // Functionality
                    slideshow               :   1,          // Slideshow on/off
                    autoplay                :   1,          // Slideshow starts playing automatically
                    start_slide             :   1,          // Start slide (0 is random)
                    stop_loop               :   0,          // Pauses slideshow on last slide
                    random                  :   0,          // Randomize slide order (Ignores start slide)
                    slide_interval          :   3000,       // Length between transitions
                    transition              :   6,          // 0-None, 1-Fade, 2-Slide Top, 3-Slide Right, 4-Slide Bottom, 5-Slide Left, 6-Carousel Right, 7-Carousel Left
                    transition_speed        :   1000,       // Speed of transition
                    new_window              :   1,          // Image links open in new window/tab
                    pause_hover             :   0,          // Pause slideshow on hover
                    keyboard_nav            :   1,          // Keyboard navigation on/off
                    performance             :   1,          // 0-Normal, 1-Hybrid speed/quality, 2-Optimizes image quality, 3-Optimizes transition speed // (Only works for Firefox/IE, not Webkit)
                    image_protect           :   1,          // Disables image dragging and right click with Javascript

                    // Size & Position                         
                    min_width               :   0,          // Min width allowed (in pixels)
                    min_height              :   0,          // Min height allowed (in pixels)
                    vertical_center         :   1,          // Vertically center background
                    horizontal_center       :   1,          // Horizontally center background
                    fit_always              :   0,          // Image will never exceed browser width or height (Ignores min. dimensions)
                    fit_portrait            :   1,          // Portrait images will not exceed browser height
                    fit_landscape           :   0,          // Landscape images will not exceed browser width

                    // Components                           
                    slide_links             :   'blank',    // Individual links for each slide (Options: false, 'number', 'name', 'blank')
                    thumb_links             :   1,          // Individual thumb links for each slide
                    thumbnail_navigation    :   0,          // Thumbnail navigation
                    slides                  :   [           // Slideshow Images
                                                        {image : 'http://buildinternet.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/supersized/3.2/slides/kazvan-1.jpg', title : 'Image Credit: Maria Kazvan', thumb : 'http://buildinternet.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/supersized/3.2/thumbs/kazvan-1.jpg', url : 'http://www.nonsensesociety.com/2011/04/maria-kazvan/'},
                                                        {image : 'http://buildinternet.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/supersized/3.2/slides/kazvan-2.jpg', title : 'Image Credit: Maria Kazvan', thumb : 'http://buildinternet.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/supersized/3.2/thumbs/kazvan-2.jpg', url : 'http://www.nonsensesociety.com/2011/04/maria-kazvan/'},  
                                                        {image : 'http://buildinternet.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/supersized/3.2/slides/kazvan-3.jpg', title : 'Image Credit: Maria Kazvan', thumb : 'http://buildinternet.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/supersized/3.2/thumbs/kazvan-3.jpg', url : 'http://www.nonsensesociety.com/2011/04/maria-kazvan/'},
                                                        {image : 'http://buildinternet.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/supersized/3.2/slides/wojno-1.jpg', title : 'Image Credit: Colin Wojno', thumb : 'http://buildinternet.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/supersized/3.2/thumbs/wojno-1.jpg', url : 'http://www.nonsensesociety.com/2011/03/colin/'},
                                                        {image : 'http://buildinternet.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/supersized/3.2/slides/wojno-2.jpg', title : 'Image Credit: Colin Wojno', thumb : 'http://buildinternet.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/supersized/3.2/thumbs/wojno-2.jpg', url : 'http://www.nonsensesociety.com/2011/03/colin/'},
                                                        {image : 'http://buildinternet.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/supersized/3.2/slides/wojno-3.jpg', title : 'Image Credit: Colin Wojno', thumb : 'http://buildinternet.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/supersized/3.2/thumbs/wojno-3.jpg', url : 'http://www.nonsensesociety.com/2011/03/colin/'},
                                                        {image : 'http://buildinternet.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/supersized/3.2/slides/shaden-1.jpg', title : 'Image Credit: Brooke Shaden', thumb : 'http://buildinternet.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/supersized/3.2/thumbs/shaden-1.jpg', url : 'http://www.nonsensesociety.com/2011/06/brooke-shaden/'},
                                                        {image : 'http://buildinternet.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/supersized/3.2/slides/shaden-2.jpg', title : 'Image Credit: Brooke Shaden', thumb : 'http://buildinternet.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/supersized/3.2/thumbs/shaden-2.jpg', url : 'http://www.nonsensesociety.com/2011/06/brooke-shaden/'},
                                                        {image : 'http://buildinternet.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/supersized/3.2/slides/shaden-3.jpg', title : 'Image Credit: Brooke Shaden', thumb : 'http://buildinternet.s3.amazonaws.com/projects/supersized/3.2/thumbs/shaden-3.jpg', url : 'http://www.nonsensesociety.com/2011/06/brooke-shaden/'}
                                                ],

                    // Theme Options               
                    progress_bar            :   1,          // Timer for each slide                         
                    mouse_scrub             :   0

                });
            });

    </script>
</head>
```

The images load and the slideshow works, but there are no nav arrows, thumbnail tray or the main thing that I want, captions. I tried initially to enqueue the scripts from functions.php but that was not working so I was trying to pinpoint the issue. Another ball in the chain is, if I add the supersized plugin for WP, along with the NextGen gallery, it all works fine. I get the tray, progress bar and captions. The reason I do not want to use the plugins is I want to control the captions in a more granular level by pulling the images and captions from a CPT. That point is moot though if I cannot get captions from the basic implementation. I am wondering if I am missing a load parameter or a load order. All resources load successfully, so i dont know why it would not reciprocate from the demo site, unless there was some conflict.

Comment: Do you see any error in console? Can you post the link to your site here?

Comment: The site is not live yet. No errors in the console though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was because of a stupid mistake on my part.

You have to include the Id hooks in the body to get the captions. I thought those were created through the js, but not true. You have to provide the html framework for the captions, progress bar, etc to render properly. So, in your `<body>`, add

```
<!--Thumbnail Navigation-->
    <div id="prevthumb"></div>
    <div id="nextthumb"></div>

    <!--Arrow Navigation-->
    <a id="prevslide" class="load-item"></a>
    <a id="nextslide" class="load-item"></a>

    <div id="thumb-tray" class="load-item">
        <div id="thumb-back"></div>
        <div id="thumb-forward"></div>
    </div>

    <!--Time Bar-->
    <div id="progress-back" class="load-item">
        <div id="progress-bar"></div>
    </div>

    <!--Control Bar-->
    <div id="controls-wrapper" class="load-item">
        <div id="controls">

            <a id="play-button"><img id="pauseplay" src="img/pause.png"/></a>

            <!--Slide counter-->
            <div id="slidecounter">
                <span class="slidenumber"></span> / <span class="totalslides"></span>
            </div>

            <!--Slide captions displayed here-->
            <div id="slidecaption"></div>

            <!--Thumb Tray button-->
            <a id="tray-button"><img id="tray-arrow" src="img/button-tray-up.png"/></a>

            <!--Navigation-->
            <ul id="slide-list"></ul>

        </div>
    </div>
```

This is not explicit on the [supersized](http://buildinternet.com/project/supersized/) site, but if you pay attention (like I should have done) to the demo files provided, it explains all.